# NPM build script doesn't run

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to run `babel` as a build step in my project, but it doesn't seem to work.

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "module-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Module",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8"
  }
}
```

And `.babelrc`, in the same directory, looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

The command `npm test` works fine and the Karma tests run. But when I use `npm build --verbose`, I just get the following output:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'build',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.2
npm info using node@v6.9.3
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

But the Babel command did not run and the build directory is not created. However, running the command `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d build` directly from the command line works perfectly.

Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

Comment: did u try "npm run build"?

Comment: For what it's worth, I make this mistake at least once with every Webpack project I set up!

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do stuff like `./node_modules/.bin/cmd --args` in your npm scripts, you can just do `cmd --args`.  npm scripts automatically look in the `.bin` directory for executables when they run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm test` is a [built in npm command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test), but your `build` command is not built in.

For npm commands that are *not* built in you need to `run` them:

`npm run build`

Comment: To be a little pedantic - [`npm build`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build) is a built in NPM command, it just isn't equivalent to `npm run build`. The only ones that act that way are `test`, `start`, `stop` and `restart`.

Comment: As @JoeClay mentioned, you need a way to differentiate your `build` from the `npm build` command.  All user-defined commands need `run`.  `test` is special because it has `pretest` etc.

Comment: Ok. But it is a little confusing that the the script for the built-in `test` command is defined in the same place as the custom ones. Even more confusing for me was that there is an entirely _unrelated_ `npm build` command!